# Wait for user to dismiss Modal View before executing code (Swift 2.0)

Tags: swift, tableview, segue, modalviewcontroller

I'm building an app that asks users to select a location if they don't allow access to their current location using a Modal that **Presents Modally** as soon as the user clicks 'Deny'. This modal has information displayed as a TableView, and the modal dismisses as soon as the user selects a row. I save this selection in a variable called `selectedStop`. **I want the app to pause until the user selects a location, then as soon as the user selects a location, the app continues and the setUpMap() function executes**. I've tried using an infinite `while` loop in setUpMap() and using a boolean to break out of it as soon as a user selects a row, but the while loop executes before the Modal even pops up.

**ViewController.swift**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var selectedStop: Int!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // If we don't have access to the user's current location, request for it
        if (CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() != CLAuthorizationStatus.AuthorizedWhenInUse) {
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        }
    }

    func setUpMap() {
        // do stuff with var selectedStop
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        switch status {
        case .Denied:
            // if user denies access, display modal
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("NotifyModally", sender: self)
            setUpMap() // need this func to execute AFTER location is selected
            break

        case .AuthorizedWhenInUse:
            setUpMap()
            break

        default:
            break
        }
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
        if (segue.identifier == "NotifyModally") {
            let destViewController:ModalViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! ModalViewController
            // send selectedStop var to ModalViewController
            destViewController.selectedStop = selectedStop
        }
    }
}
```

**ModalViewController.swift**

```
class ModalViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var busStops = ["Stop 1", "Stop 2", "Stop 3"]
    var selectedStop: Int!

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return busStops.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell()
        cell.textLabel!.text = busStops[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        selectedStop = indexPath.row
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `Int` variable to pass information will not working since it's a *value* type which will get copied every time you pass it around. So that means when you change the `selectedStop` in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method, the original `selectedStop` inside `ViewController` will still be nil or whatever it was.

And then, to answer your question. There are several ways to solve this.

1. You can either pass a `block` (instead an `int`) to the `ModalViewController` like this:

   ```
   var stopSelectedHandler: (Int) -> Void = { selectedStop in
       // Do something here.
       // setUpMap()
   }
   ```

You'll call this block inside the `completion` handler of `dismissViewControllerAnimated`.

2. You can use notification.

   ```
   // Do this inside `ViewController`.
   NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "setupMap:", name: "UserDidSelectStop", object: nil)

   // And then post the notification inside `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`
   NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("UserDidSelectStop", object: nil, userInfo: ["selectedStop": 2])

   // Change your setupMap to this
   func setupMap(notification: NSNotification) {
       guard let selectedStop = notification.userInfo?["selectedStop"] as? Int else { return }
       // Now you can use selectedStop.
   }
   ```

You can also use KVO, delegate, etc. Use whatever suits you.

---

Put the block like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var stopSelectedHandler: (Int) -> Void = { selectedStop in
        // Do something here.
        // setUpMap()
    }
    ....
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. How do I pass the ``block`` to the MVC? Do I do ``destViewController.selectedStop = stopSelectedHandler``?

Comment: @Ivan yes, you'll have to declare a block variable inside destViewController as well. `var stopSelectedHandler: ((Int) -> Void)?` And do `destViewController.stopSelectedHandler = stopSelectedHandler`

Comment: Where do I put ``var stopSelectedHandler: (Int) -> Void = { selectedStop in ... }``? Does that go right before ``destViewController.selectedStop = stopSelectedHandler``? I apologize for the confusion, I'm still learning Swift.

Comment: @Ivan It's fine to put it right before that. You can also treat the block as a property. Check my answer.